# "Failed to acquire token silently" error when trying to connect to Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, owin, microsoft-graph-api

We have an asp.net MVC application that is authenticating against Azure AD with OpenID connect. Users are authenticated on startup with the following code:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = ConfigHelper.ClientId,
                Authority = ConfigHelper.Authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigHelper.PostLogoutRedirectUri,

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        var code = context.Code;
                        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(ConfigHelper.ClientId, ConfigHelper.ClientSecret);
                        string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(ConfigHelper.Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                        return authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, ConfigHelper.GraphResourceId);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

Users are authenticated successfully, so far so good, but elsewhere in the application we are trying to authenticate/connect to Microsoft Graph with the following snippet from a helper class:

```
ClientCredential cred = new ClientCredential(ConfigHelper.ClientId, ConfigHelper.ClientSecret);
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(ConfigHelper.Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
        try
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(ConfigHelper.GraphResourceId, cred, new UserIdentifier(signedInUserID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
            return result.AccessToken;
        }
        catch (AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException e)
        {
            // handle exception
        }
```

Here, the `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` method always fails with the following:

```
Failed to acquire token silently as no token was found in the cache. Call method AcquireToken

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Internal.Flows.AcquireTokenSilentHandler.SendTokenRequestAsync()
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Internal.Flows.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.<CheckAndAcquireTokenUsingBrokerAsync>d__59.MoveNext()
```

In both cases a TokenCache is created with a call to `new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID)`. The `ADALTokenCache` class uses Entity Framework to persist tokens to an Azure SQL server database. Stepping through the code we see that during app startup the `ADALTokenCache` is successfully stored and read from the database when calling `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync`, but when calling `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` the token cache returns null, despite all variables being the same.

We haven't been able to find why it would succeed in the first case but fail in the second. Neither have we been able to find if it is OWIN related, Graph related or Entity Framework related.

Or is there a more preferred method of authenticating users other than OWIN for this scenario?

Any help much appreciated.

Here is our `ADALTokenCache` class:

```
public class ADALTokenCache : TokenCache
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    private string userId;
    private UserTokenCache Cache;

    public ADALTokenCache(string signedInUserId)
    {
        // Associate the cache to the current user of the web app
        userId = signedInUserId;
        this.AfterAccess = AfterAccessNotification;
        this.BeforeAccess = BeforeAccessNotification;
        this.BeforeWrite = BeforeWriteNotification;
        // Look up the entry in the database
        Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.WebUserUniqueId == userId);
        // Place the entry in memory
        this.Deserialize((Cache == null) ? null : MachineKey.Unprotect(Cache.CacheBits, "ADALCache"));
    }

    // Clean up the database
    public override void Clear()
    {
        base.Clear();
        var cacheEntry = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.WebUserUniqueId == userId);
        db.UserTokenCacheList.Remove(cacheEntry);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    // Notification raised before ADAL accesses the cache.
    // This is your chance to update the in-memory copy from the DB, if the in-memory version is stale
    void BeforeAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
    {
        if (Cache == null)
        {
            // First time access
            Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.WebUserUniqueId == userId);
        }
        else
        {
            // Retrieve last write from the DB
            var status = from e in db.UserTokenCacheList
                         where (e.WebUserUniqueId == userId)
                         select new
                         {
                             LastWrite = e.LastWrite
                         };

            // If the in-memory copy is older than the persistent copy
            if (status.First().LastWrite > Cache.LastWrite)
            {
                // Read from from storage, update in-memory copy
                Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.WebUserUniqueId == userId);
            }
        }
        this.Deserialize((Cache == null) ? null : MachineKey.Unprotect(Cache.CacheBits, "ADALCache"));
    }

    // Notification raised after ADAL accessed the cache.
    // If the HasStateChanged flag is set, ADAL changed the content of the cache
    void AfterAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
    {
        // If state changed
        if (this.HasStateChanged)
        {
            Cache = new UserTokenCache
            {
                WebUserUniqueId = userId,
                CacheBits = MachineKey.Protect(this.Serialize(), "ADALCache"),
                LastWrite = DateTime.Now
            };
            // Update the DB and the lastwrite
            db.Entry(Cache).State = Cache.UserTokenCacheId == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            this.HasStateChanged = false;
        }
    }

    void BeforeWriteNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
    {
        // If you want to ensure that no concurrent write take place, use this notification to place a lock on the entry
    }

    public override void DeleteItem(TokenCacheItem item)
    {
        base.DeleteItem(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it looks pretty good at first glance. Have you debugged `BeforeAccessNotification` when acquiring the token?

Comment: Yes I have. The command `db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault` returns null both in the constructor and in `BeforeAccessNotification`, whereas on app start it does return the `UserTokenCache`.

Comment: And you are sure an entry exists in the database with that id? Have you checked the characters are the same case? (in case your collation is case sensitive)

Comment: Yep, checked and double checked that too.

Comment: Actually, that's not true. I've been checking and double checking in debug that the ids being passed around are the same, but the id is not being written as is into the database but appears to be some kind of hash. Still perplexing why it would be able to read the hash at one point but not at another.

Comment: Some progress. Turns out the ids were not in fact the same in both cases. Changed them so that they both query the claims for the `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` value. But still getting the same error despite the token now being obtained in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Never actually got to the bottom of this, but managed to sort it out by deleting the connected services in visual studio and adding again the authentication with AAD and Graph connected services. This of course overwrote a few of the project's files with 'clean' versions, but seems to have done the trick.

Thanks juunas 4 for taking a look.